# Creating a master-detail app using NSTreeController, NSArrayController and Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm coming from iOS and trying to build the simplest master-detail OS X app possible but I'm having a hard time transitioning. More specifically, I can't really fathom how I integrate Core Data with an NSTableView using an NSArrayController;

The app currently looks this:
[image: Contacts app]

My data model looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it's very simple. I want to be able to select a Group in the source list left, then display all containing Persons in the table view right.

I've managed to connect the NSOutlineView to a simple NSArray, but what is the best way to connect it to all Group objects, using an NSTreeController, and make it all editable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `NSArrayController` and connect it to your `Group` entity (call it `GroupController`). Select the table column of your left source view and go to the bindings inspector. Select the `Value` section and bind it to `GroupController` by checking the box. Complete the binding by setting `Controller Key` to `arrangedObjects` and `Model Key Path` to `title`.

Add another `NSArrayController` (`PersonsController`). Go to the bindings inspector and select the section called `Content Set`.  Select your GroupController from the dropdown list and check the checkbox to bind `PersonsController` to `GroupController`. Complete the binding by setting `Controller Key` to `selection` and `Model Key Path` to `persons`. This will retrieve the persons connected to the selected group into the `PersonsController`

You can then bind a table view in the right hand side of your window to the PersonsController. Connect each column of the table to the PersonsController (firstName, lastName).

Editability can be set at the column level of the table view on your Person entity.

EDIT: Oops, just reread your question and saw you want an NSTreeController. I think you can replace the GroupController - which is a plain NSArrayController - with an NSTreeController. I do not see any hierarchies in your Group entity. [Here](http://lifeasclay.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/connecting-nsoutlineview-to-core-data-in-10-6-part-1-ordered-trees/#comment-212) is good tutorial with code for a tree controller that supports entities with hierarchies.

EDIT2: Another good tutorial is Apple's [SourceView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004441) example. It shows how to setup a Source View using an NSTreeController. It's data source is bound to file based NSDictionary but using the other tutorial and the description of the required bindings in my answer you should be able to get that working.

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily want an NSTreeController, but I want to use a source list to display my Group objects, because I want the "GROUPS" header above them. Is that possible using an NSArrayController? The tutorial doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: No, AFAIK I know you must use the NSOutlineView and an NSTreeController. I built my master/detail app using that tutorial and it works great. The tutorial actually uses two controllers: one NSArrayController to retrieve top level items (using a predicate parent == nil) and then an NSTreeController to display the actual tree.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at the example code SourceView:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html

It uses an NSOutlineView driven by NSTreeController.